# How to build completely a codenameone plugin based on specific "commit" of Codenameone's GitHub Project?

Tags: codenameone

My team needs to bring immediately to customers a fix in Codename One that will only be available in next version.

> (GitHub commit: [ddc2356ee77eefb64425bcdd0d8ed5aab30505bf](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/ddc2356ee77eefb64425bcdd0d8ed5aab30505bf))
>
> (GitHub issue: [#2203](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2203))

Unfortunately we can't wait for the November 2017 planned release of the new plugin version.

So, we need to configure a new Plugin locally with this fix and use it to build a new Android Application for deployment. How do we go about that?

We already cloned the GitHub's Codenameone Project and read some documentation, but we couldn't find required information.

Comment: FYI building the Codename One code doesn't require you to build a new plugin it's actually really easy to work with the code without updating a plugin https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That commit will be included in the next server update next Friday.  You don't need to wait until November.